# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: moderators

As we enter the second week of the public beta, we desperately need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image]

LATE ENTRY NOTICE: We've recently added two new Moderators to this site: hobodave and Aaronut. It is unusual to have this many Moderators added so early but their contributions to this site could no longer go unrecognized.

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: I for one am glad that hobodave and Aaronut have been made moderators.  I feel they contribute more than most to the site and that recognition is fully deserved.  If there are too many moderators I'm happy to step aside.

Comment: @Sam: Thank you. And stop this crazy talk of stepping aside.

Comment: It wouldn't be advisable to have every other user be a moderator but in the new generation of sites, moderators play double duty: Traditional site moderation *and* getting the process going of driving new traffic to the site. I really wanted to put this selection of users in a favorable position for the programs we have planned, even at the risk of having too many cooks (oy, I can't believe I went for the pun).

Comment: I am absolutely, 100% pro-tempura.  The shrimp is my favourite kind.  (Also, thanks @Sam!)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, (PT) moderators.

May I suggest (to all and any readers, most who will agree with me anyway), that we don't couple in-depth cooking knowledge/skills to moderator/"community grower" ability too tightly? I don't want to double-burden these moderators with a content-burden at the same time.

There's no competition or top-cheffing here anyway, but anyway, godspeed to the (PT) moderators.